# difference between print drupal_get_form and return drupal_get_form

Tags: php, drupal-6

what is the difference between

```
     print drupal_get_form('user_register');
```

and

```
    return drupal_get_form('user_register');
```

I am a newbie in drupal...  I would be thankful to any explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your callback if you write print drupal_get_form('form_id') then drupal prints the form in the callback, but if you write return drupal_get_form('form_id') then you must catch the returned html in a variable and then print the variable which contains the html of the form.